# Replace distinct values of list with values of another list

Tags: list-manipulation

First of all I´m new to Mathematica; I´m trying to exchange distinct values of a list with values of another list (piecewise). I thought `ReplacePart` in combination with `Position` will do it, but it doesn´t yield the wanted result.

Here is an example:

original data:

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[]*100, {x, 0, 20}, {y, 0, 20}, {z, 0, 20}];
```

next get the position:

```
posSelect = Position[data, a_ /; a == 100, {3}, Heads -> False];
```

generate 2nd list:

```
lengthSelect = Length[Extract[data, posSelect]];
newVal = RandomInteger[1, lengthSelect];
```

updated list

```
data2 = data
data2 = ReplacePart[data, posSelect -> newVal];
```

data2 now contains at each selected position the entire elements of newVal. What is wrong with this approach? How to correctly exchange these selected values with the values of the 2nd list?

Comment: fyi, instead of `posSelect = Position[data, a_ /; a == 100, {3}, Heads -> False];` you just write `posSelect = Position[data, 100, {3}, Heads -> False];`

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch No, that doesn't work because `posSelect` is not a list of integers but rather a list of lists of integers, so you'll have to `Map` your way around this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace every occurrence of `100` with a random choice of `0` or `1`, this suffices:

```
data = Table[RandomInteger[]*100, {2}, {2}, {2}]
```

> {{{100, 100}, {0, 0}}, {{100, 100}, {0, 100}}}

```
data /. (100 :> RandomInteger[])
```

> {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}}

Note that I've limited the `data` array to 2x2x2 instead of 20x20x20 for simplicity.
However, if you want to stick a second list of values, you can do this:

```
newVal = RandomInteger[1, Count[data, 100, {3}]]
```

> {0, 1, 1, 1, 0}

```
index = 0;
data2 = data /. (100 :> newVal[[ ++index ]])
```

> {{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}}

Or alternatively, if you have a healthy aversion against loop variables, you can do the following:

```
positions = Position[data, 100]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}

```
data2 = ReplacePart[data, Thread[positions -> newVal] ]
```

> {{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 0}}}

This is the closest to what you actually asked. Turns out you were only missing a call to [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) :).

Comment: Nice job covering the bases.

Comment: Nice alternatives +1